# CPU goes over 100% and app freezes in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, multithreading

I am calling 4-5 request parallel to get data from server and saves it into coreData. I amusing alamofire to make request.

But app is got freezing for 5-10 seconds & CPU is goes 100% or more than that.

I am sure that this request uses cpu power.

I am also try with background queue but no effect of it.

My code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

            APIManager.sharedInstance.download_categories { (json, value, error) in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.loadCategory()
                 })

            }

            APIManager.sharedInstance.download_countries { (json, value, error) in

            }

            APIManager.sharedInstance.download_Subdivision { (json, value, error) in

               // HUD.hide()
            }

            APIManager.sharedInstance.download_paymentTerms { (json, value, error) in

            }

            APIManager.sharedInstance.download_currency { (json, value, error) in

            }

                })
```

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: are you doing operation on Coredata on main thread

Comment: @ankit, yes I saves data into coredata on main thread.
if I do coredata operation in background then it raise fault while fetching objects.

Comment: well you can do it via concurrency. try it https://cocoacasts.com/core-data-and-concurrency/